What is an alternative way to show that a sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying $|x_{n+1} - x_n| < \frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is Cauchy?
This problem is from an intro to real analysis. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence satisfying
$$|x_{n+1} - x_n| < \dfrac{1}{2^n}$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ The first approach I took was to use the definition of a Cauchy sequence. Without loss of generality, I assumed that $n > m$. Then, by the Triangle Inequality and the partial sum formula for geometric series,
$$\begin{align*} |x_n - x_m| &= |(x_n - x_{n-1}) + (x_{n-1} - x_{n-2}) + \cdots + (x_{m+1} - x_m)| \\ &\leq |x_n - x_{n-1}| + |x_{n-1} - x_{n-2}| + \cdots + |x_{m+1} - x_m| \\ &< \dfrac{1}{2^{m}} + \dfrac{1}{2^{m+1}} + \dfrac{1}{2^{m+2}} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}} \\ &= \sum_{i = 1}^{n-m}\dfrac{1}{2^m}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{i-1} \\ &= \dfrac{1}{2^m}\cdot\dfrac{1-(1/2)^{n-m}}{1-(1/2)} \\ &= 2(2^{-m}-2^{-n}).\end{align*}$$
I found that, in order to make the last expression arbitrarily smaller than any $\varepsilon > 0,$ I required that the indices $n$ and $m$ be greater than or equal to a natural number $H \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $H > 1 - \log_2(\varepsilon).$ Only then would I be able to write a more formal proof. Is there an alternative, more elegant way to utilize a familiar theorem or lemma that can help me avoid having to figure out a lower bound for $H$ in the first place? For example, I could probably either use the Squeeze Theorem, or use the Cauchy Convergence Criterion, or even show first that this $(x_n)$ sequence is contractive by picking a real number $C ∈ (0,1)$ such that
$$|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}| \leq C|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ then use the fact that every contractive sequence is a Cauchy sequence. I felt like I was onto something here; too bad I couldn't help but kept going in circles and ended up being stumped.

You don’t need such a sharp bound. You can factor the last expression and then get a much looser upper bound that still goes to $0$.

Or even easier than that, it’s less than $2^{1-m}$ which goes to $0$ with $m$.

I might’ve been very late, but I just want to thank you @Malady. Since it’s less than $2^{1-m}$ which goes to $0,$ I can pick $H \in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large enough so that $2^{1 - H} < \varepsilon.$ You really saved my life back then; I just wasn’t sure if I could properly say thanks in a comment on Math Exchange. Merry Christmas and/or Happy Holidays!
